# Cannot find export button in rhythmbox to rip audio cd

Tags: rhythmbox, cd, cd-ripping

This is is my first try to rip an audio cd to flac files.

I am using ubuntu 17.10 and rhythmbox opened automatically after inserting the cd.

I did not find much information about this topic online, but it looks like there must be some "Export" button somewhere. Some tutorials mentioned that a right click on the disc opens a context menu with an entry "Import to library".

I cannot find any Export button and when I right click the disc, nothing happens.

How to proceed from here?

[image: Screenshot of Rhythmbox]

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the menu from your screenshot.

Click on "View" then check "Select source toolbar"

Four buttons should appear along the top, one of which is "Extract"

Answer (score 0):

[image]r

It may be hided "Source toolbar"

It my be wrong because I use Japanese version.